# script what to do if ls -lrtd returns file or directory does not exists

Tags: linux, bash

This is a part of a script I'm trying to write.

If the directory exist there is no problem, but I don't know what to do if it not exists.

Some one has an idea how to solve this.

Thanks

```
do echo "$number"

newdir="../FILE-ID/*/${number:2:1}${number:1:1}/+33$number"

nbrdir=$(ls -lrtd $newdir|wc -l)

echo "$nbrdir"

if [ "$nbrdir" -gt 1 ]; then

   echo "$number"
   echo "error 1.greater"

fi

if [ "$nbrdir" -eq 1 ]; then

     echo " equal 1"

else

   echo "equal 0"

fi

done
```

Comment: The code you have looks like it will be able to detect how many matches `$newdir` has. Are you asking how to stop the `ls: cannot access <file>: No such file or directory` message from printing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following to test whether a file (including a directory) exists:

```
if [[ -f ${newdir} ]]; then ...
```

or another switch if you want to test specifically just for a directory:

```
if [[ -d ${newdir} ]]; then ...
```

A more comprehensive list can be found [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html).

If your directory name contains wildcards and matches potentially zero or more, you can use:

```
nbrdir=$(ls -1d ${newdir} 2>/dev/null | wc -l)
```

This should give you a count of matching directories. Note that any error message which might be generated will be directed to /dev/null which is *probably* what you want here to avoid errors messing up your output.

Comment: Problem is that in the newdir there is a " *  " ,  I don't know where there directory is  can be in /FILE-ID/00  or in FILE-ID/99  or any mumber in between.

Comment: @BigBen59: Understood. This should be relatively straightforward. I've added an appropriate solution above.

Answer (score 0):

[ -d $newdir ] && echo "Directory exists" || echo "Directory does not exists"